# Im having trouble understanding a question regarding vectors without coordinates.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Given $\|\vec{a}\|=1$, $\|\vec{b}\|=2$, $\|\vec{c}\|=2$, $\vec{c}=2\vec{a}+\vec{b}$, I need to find the angle $α$ between vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

This is the solution provided (via the scalar product/inner product(?)):
$$ \begin{align}
\vec{c}\cdot\vec{c} &= (2\vec{a}+\vec{b})\cdot(2\vec{a}+\vec{b})=|2\vec{a}+\vec{b}|^2\cdot\cos{(\alpha)} \\
&=4|\vec{a}|^2+|\vec{b}|^2+4|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\cdot\cos{(\alpha)}=4 \\
&\Rightarrow\cos{(\alpha)}=-\frac{1}{2}
\end{align} $$
Shouldn't there be brackets, as in: $(4|\vec{a}|^2+|\vec{b}|^2+4|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|)\cdot\cos{(\alpha)}=4$? Is there a rule that I'm not aware of?

Comment: If you just draw the picture for $c=2a+b$, you get a triangle whose side lengths are known, and the answer becomes obvious.

Comment: Big hint: law of cosines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clerical error of the solution is actually in the part before:

$$(2\vec{a}+\vec{b})\cdot(2\vec{a}+\vec{b})=|2\vec{a}+\vec{b}|^2\color{red}{\cdot\cos{(\alpha)}}.$$

The scalar product of a vector ($(2\vec{a}+\vec{b})$ in this case) with itself is always equal to the square of its length, there is no need for a factor of $\cos \alpha$.

The solution then correctly continues to expand the product on the left above, replaces $2\vec{a}\cdot 2\vec{a}$ with $4|\vec{a}|^2$ and similar for products of  $\vec{b}$ with itself. The only thing it cannot directly replace with the length of a vector is the $4\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}$ part, but that can be expressed using the geometric definition of the inner product

$$4\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} = 4|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\cos(\alpha).$$

The the solution continues correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! Ive been stuck on this Question for 2 days!